# How to display the content after contact form submitted?

Tags: php, email, contacts, contact-form

i watched a tutorial that teaches how to create simple php form from Youtube. I follow the instruction and created the form, now the form is working alright, but there is a problem i facing with the form. That is, i got no idea how to display full data of the form field to be display on the email after the contact form submitted. Here i have the php code of process_contact.php.

Click this link to see the attachment of the php code that i have for the contact form.
http://www.ytcopier.com.my/img/process_contact.jpg

At the moment, i can only see the field of $inquiry. Can someone guide me what to do in order to display all the field? Thank you! Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: $inquiry is the body of your email. Change it to whatever pleases you.

Comment: No idea how to change it. I'm a newbie to php coding. Hope to get some correct instructs to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a message having all the required details in email. something like this

```
$emailMsg = "Details: <br/> Contact Person: {$contactperson} <br/> Phone Number: {$phonenumber} <br/> Email : {$emailaddress} <br/> Company Name: {$companyname} <br/> Company Address: {$companyaddress} <br/> Service Inquired: {$serviceinquire} <br/> Find Us: {$findus} <br/> Inquiry: {$inquiry} <br/> ";
```

Insert the above in your code.

Replace this

```
mail($to,$subject,$inquiry,"From: YTCopier");
```

to

```
mail($to,$subject,$emailMsg,"From: YTCopier");
```

For next time don't attach an image of the code, paste the code here itself.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for your prompt response! Sorry for that! I tried your code, but it doesn't work. Is there any error between the code? Thank you!

Comment: I tried the code you suggested, but it does't work. All the values turn back with blank value. Not sure what's going wrong. Will you figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: @Jornes did you get a email after insert/replace above code in your code? plz paste the email content here.

Comment: Hi Rohit, yes! I got an email after submitted. But all the values come back with blank.

Comment: @Jornes please share the new code here after all the edits you did as per above?.